# Consistent GUIDs for custom data provider

Tags: integration, data-provider

I am creating a custom data provider to integration news articles from an external API into a Sitecore solution.

The external data source use simple integers as ID for the news articles though.
I will be running the data provider in "live mode" (directly in both master and web databases without publishing). How do i generate consistent GUIDs from the ID, so that the GUID will be the same across both databases?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sitecore Commerce Connect employs a similar approach. From the [Commerce Connect Integration Guide](https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/products/sitecore%20commerce%20connect/sitecore_connect_integration_guide_usletter.pdf):

> 3.1.5 ID Mapping By design, the remote product repository is always regarded as the main repository, which by default owns the products.
>
> That makes the ID of the products and artifacts in the external system
> the primary key.
>
> In Sitecore, the IDs of the corresponding items for
> products and artifacts are generated by Connect instead of relying on
> the default Sitecore implementation that automatically generates a new
> GUID for each new item created.
>
> By using a hash algorithm, it is
> possible to generate a direct mapping between the IDs coming from the
> external system and the item IDs in Sitecore. It has the following
> benefits:
>
> - No need for mapping tables taking up space.
> - It becomes very fast to get the ID of the corresponding item.
> - There is no need for searching for the items in Sitecore if the external ID is provided.
>
> The default implementation is based on the MD5 hash
> algorithm and has the following format:
>
> `Item.ID = MD5.ComputeHash(Prefix + ExternalID);`

So essentially; make a Sitecore ID based on prefix (which would be your entity type; "product", "category", "customer" and so on) and the foreign unique key of the entity. That should bring you to the same ID result every time.

Answer (score 5):

You should try to write a function to generate deterministic guids. Found this: http://kechengpuzi.com/q/s2642141 as a possibility (example is based on paths, but you can use your id as input - if needed with a pre- or suffix).

It actually comes down to creating a hash and calling the Guid constructor with that.

I did not copy the example code here as they mention a few possible solutions and I didn't try them myself so it's not clear which is best.

Answer (score 1):

I have had to do similar in the past have used deterministic GUIDs. I use the method described and shared here:

http://code.logos.com/blog/2011/04/generating_a_deterministic_guid.html

This algorithm follows [RFC 4122](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt), and is designed not to clash with GUIDs that are generated in other namespaces - so it won't clash with `Guid.NewGuid()` for example.

Using MD5 hashes directly works but they don't come with the guarantee of avoiding clashes with other GUIDs.